# Does a wsdl needs to be valid wsdl file in order for it to work

Tags: xml, wsdl, xsd, schema

My question may sound odd at first place but need to make sure.

I received the following wsdl from client which I can import successfully in SoapUI and use in my application. But when I try to validate wsdl file, it throws 12 errors

```
<wsdl:types>
    <schema  targetNamespace="http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService/types/"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <element name="Message">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                     <any minOccurs="0"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </schema>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://abc.com:9080/nproduct/services/12WebService/types/"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <element name="Response">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                     <any minOccurs="0"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="Message">
    <wsdl:part name="Message" element="types:Message"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="Response">
    <wsdl:part name="Response" element="types:Response"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="12WebServiceImpl">
    <wsdl:operation name="process12">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:Message" name="Message"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:Response" name="Response"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="tns:Response" name="Response"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="12WebServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:12WebServiceImpl">
    <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="process12">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService/process12"/>
        <wsdl:input name="Message">
            <wsdlsoap:body namespace="http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="Response">
            <wsdlsoap:body namespace="http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="Response">
            <wsdlsoap:body namespace="http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService" use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="12WebService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:12WebServiceSoapBinding" name="12WebService">
        <wsdlsoap:address location="http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

So, does a `wsdl` need to be valid. Shall i go back to client to correct it?

Comment: Which validation errors are you getting?

Comment: All the validation errors were related to `NCName`. Name like `12WebService` cannot start with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

i think the wsdl file have to be validated.
XML naming rules: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

> XML Naming Rules XML elements must follow these naming rules:
>
> Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
>   Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
>   Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
>   Names cannot contain spaces
>   Any name can be used, no words are reserved.